# Can Snapchat sue me if I use name "Snap" in my commercial project?

Tags: copyright, criminal-law, intellectual-property

I plan to name my commercial web project as ____Snap.
My website will be unrelated to what SnapChat is offering and in a different industry, but idea of short living content is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the question "can so-and-so sue me?" is almost always "yes", regardless of context.  Such a suit might be baseless, and it might get settled in your favor, but you still have to spend the time and money to defend yourself.  This can be disastrous for a start-up that's trying to get off the ground, and it's how [patent trolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_troll) make their money.  (I'm not accusing SnapChat of engaging in such tactics as a rule, of course;  I'm just pointing out that the legal system does allow for them.)

Whether or not you are *likely* to be sued is a separate question, and one that can really only be effectively addressed by a trademark attorney with full knowledge of the particularities of your situation.